# Using afterFind in cakePHP to determine if the result count is 0?

Tags: php, cakephp, model

So I am trying to setup the afterFind function provided by cakePHP to determine whether any results are returned from the query.

When testing the debug output this is what I received:

```
Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() [APP/Model/Form.php, line 70]    

app/Model/Form.php (line 71)
'0'
```

This behavior seems very odd, as it tells me I am supplying and Invalid arguement provided in my foreach loop but at the same time it is able to determine that 0 is the correct count of the query on the database.

This is the function below located in my Form.php model.

```
public function afterFind($results, $primary = true){
     foreach ($results as $key => $val) {
         debug($val[0]['count']);
     }
}
```

I am attempting to do it this way because in my controller I am trying to paginate the results, BUT if the count of the results is 0 then I want to $this->Session->Setflash();

As far as I can tell the `$this->Form->Find()` function can calculate the total count of the results.

The count ability does not work with `$this->paginate('Form) 
ex. $this->paginate('count', 'Form');]`

Is there an alternative way of doing this?

Comment: You need to look at the format of `$results` - it isn't what you expect. Moreover, counts (obviously) aren't the only type of query that hits the afterFind callback/method, so even if there was no error from your count call - there would be an undefined index error from all other find calls. `I am trying to paginate the results.` - then use the built in [pagination](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html) functions =). `The count ability does not work with $this->paginate('Form);` - how so? You're asking the wrong question.

Comment: I have updated my question to be more clear.  

$this->paginate('count', 'Form) does not work like $this->Form->Find('count') though I need my results to still be paginated but also be able to tell whether or not my results are 0

Comment: where have you seen `$this->paginate('count', 'Form')`? I think the answer to "Is there an alternative way of doing this" is: yes - just follow [the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html).

Comment: I was trying to keep the code to a minimum.  For instance, rather than Querying for the results twice.  Once for the count $this->Form->Find('count', 'all'), and then again if the count is you find the pagination results. 

This all coincides with why I was using the afterFind method.  I wanted to determine a 0 result answer before I called the pagination method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do it wrong. If you would paginate the results by yourself you do a separate find('count') query first to get the total number of records and by the limit you already know the maximum of records per page.

CakePHP comes with built in pagination functionality. Read this section of the book. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html A few paragraphs down there is a section about building customized pagination methods if that is what you try to do.